# Microsoft unit testing. Is it possible to skip test from test method body?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

So I have situation when I need skip current test from test method body.
Simplest way is to write something like this in test method.

```
if (something) return;
```

But I have a lot complicated tests and I need a way to skip test from methods which I invoke in current test method body.
Is it possible?

Comment: My utterly instinctive response is to ask _why_? =) And you can always do an `Assert.Pass();` or `Assert.Fail();`. But otherwise... tests are there to be run. =)

Comment: Why skip the test? Shouldn't you either return Assert.Fail() or Assert.Inconclusive()?

Comment: I'd suggest `Assert.Inconclusive` over `Assert.Fail`, since it's not an explicit failure case.  `Inconclusive` makes it clearer that you *don't know* whether the test succeeded or failed.

Comment: `Assert.Inconclusive` is thing I`m looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Further to other answers (and as suggested): I'd suggest using `Assert.Inconclusive` over `Assert.Fail`, since the original poster's situation is not an explicit failure case.

Using `Inconclusive` as a result makes it clear that you don't know whether the test succeeded or failed - which is an important distinction.  Not proving success doesn't always constitute failure!

Comment: Many years later and MSTest -> TFS finally recognizes Assert.Inconclusive as "Other" instead of "Fail". See https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/525 for details if this is as important to you as it is to me :-).

Answer (score 112):

You should not skip test this way. Better do one of following things:

- mark test as ignored via `[Ignore]` attribute
- throw `NotImplementedException` from your test
- write `Assert.Fail()` (otherwise you can forget to complete this test)
- remove this test

Also keep in mind, that your tests should not contain conditional logic. Instead you should create two tests - separate test for each code path (with name, which describes what conditions you are testing). So, instead of writing:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestFooBar()
{
   // Assert foo
   if (!bar)
      return;
   // Assert bar
}
```

Write two tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestFoo()
{
   // set bar == false
   // Assert foo
}

[Ignore] // you can ignore this test
[TestMethod]
public void TestBar()
{
   // set bar == true
   // Assert bar
}
```

Comment: ....very good option, I was searching for this, thanks anyway Sergey ..upvoted.

Answer (score 19):

You can ignore a test and leave it completely untouched in the code.

```
[TestMethod()]
[Ignore()]    //ignores the test below
public void SomeTestCodeTest()
{
   //test code here

}
```

Comment: I think he means programmatically decide this from inside the test, similar to NUnit's Assume.

Comment: Just for the sake of concision: [TestMethod, Ignore]

Answer (score 4):

There is an `Assert.Inconclusive()` method which you can use to nicely skip the current test. Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.inconclusive?view=mstest-net-1.2.0). Basically it will throw an exception and will show this method as `Skipped`.

I used this as a programmatic check in my code inside the test method:

```
if (!IsEnvironmentConfigured())
{
   Assert.Inconclusive("Some message");
}
```

Here is the result:

```
! ShouldTestThisMethod [31ms]

Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 92
     Passed: 91
    Skipped: 1
 Total time: 1.2518 Seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Of interest.....you can also extend the TestMethodAttribute class to avoid writing the same logic in all tests.  I have a variety of "proto" tests that I run manually from time to time (often these tests make a call to a database or REST api, so I obviously don't want them running with the pipeline).

```
internal class DebugOnlyTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
{
    public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
    {
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            return new[]
                {
                    new TestResult
                    {
                        Outcome = UnitTestOutcome.Inconclusive,
                        TestContextMessages = "This test can only be run with a debugger attached."
                    }
                };
        }

        return base.Execute(testMethod);
    }
}
```